# Drumming bridge/crescendo

Tags: terminology, drums, snare-drum

Do drummers have a name for this particular kind of bridge/crescendo, for example:

Life in the Fast Lane - Eagles (3:57)

Who We Are - Camel (4:22)

Comment: I guess bridge/crescendo is as good as it gets.

Comment: Buildup? "Fill" often applies though it's not quite what I'm hearing here

Comment: Interesting. On a quick search it looks like producers call it a buildup but drummers don't use that word. I don't have an answer.

Comment: If it’s not a *fill* that you’re asking about, then the answer might be “no, there is no name for that”.

Comment: "Fill" fits, but only partially, There is a lead-up to the next section built into the thing. "Buildup" does fit but I was hoping for something more specific but that may be it.

Comment: Well, I guess there isn't a term so I'll create one ... frescendo.

Comment: Single stroke roll?